# How am I using React hooks wrong here?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a simple Phonebook to go along with FullstackOpen course from  University of Helsinki. My logs from the below code show me that my 'filterBy' state is always a render behind and I'm also getting errors from my contacts.filter that "contact.name.toUpperCase" is not a function. So i guess I have 2 questions.

1. Can I even do what they're trying to have me do without using class components? They haven't introduced them in the course yet, so I'm assuming yes. But I thought I heard in a tutorial once that class components have to be used when you need state to be in sync (e.g. using an input to filter an array of objects displayed on screen). But I can't get the filterBy state to actually be in sync with what's in the filter input.
2. I know my line starting "const contactsToShow . . ." is probably a less than optimal way to do it, if functional at all. How can this best be done?

Code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Contact from './components/Contact'

const App = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([
    { name:'Guy Fieri', number: '020-4837473'},
    { name:'Gordon Ramsay', number: '75749483832'},
    { name:'Mr. Tasty', number: '43-4982839'},
    { name:'Dude man', number: '11-33-448382'},
  ]) 
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')
  const [newNumber, setNewNumber] = useState('')
  const [showAll, setShowAll] = useState(true)
  const [filterBy, setFilterBy] = useState('');

  const contactsToShow = showAll ? contacts : contacts.filter(contact => contact.name.toUpperCase().search(filterBy) !== -1)


  const rows = () => contactsToShow.map(contact =>
    <Contact
      key={contact.name}
      name={contact.name}
      number={contact.number}
    />
  )
  
  const handleContactNameChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setNewName(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleContactNumberChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setNewNumber(event.target.value)
    console.log(newNumber);
  }

  const handleFiltering = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setFilterBy(event.target.value)
    setShowAll(false)
    console.log(filterBy);
  }

  const addContact = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    // 
    if(newName === '') return true
    if(newNumber === '') return true

    let dup = false
    contacts.forEach(contact => {
      if (contact.name === newName) dup = true
    })

    if (!dup) {
      const contactObject = {
        name: newName,
        number: newNumber
      }
  
      setContacts(contacts.concat(contactObject))
      setNewName('')
      setNewNumber('')
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Phonebook</h1>
      <form onSubmit={addContact}>
      <div>
        Filter:<input value={filterBy} onChange={handleFiltering}/>
      </div>
        Name: <input
          value={newName} 
          onChange={handleContactNameChange}
        /><br/>
        Number: <input
          value={newNumber} 
          onChange={handleContactNumberChange}
        /><br/>
        <button type="submit">save</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {rows()}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

What can I try? I'm very new to React like this.

Comment: you can do it without using classes, but i would see what they want in your assignment. And i think your `filter` method is setup wrong so that's why you're getting that `ToUpperCase` error

Comment: @mph85 Yeah, they don't really give further instructions or solutions for that matter. It's just a course from the school that's available online. They haven't introduced class components, so I'm stumped right now.

Comment: The problem is that you forgot to make `contactsToShow` a function. Use `const contactsToShow = () => showAll ...` and `const rows = () => contactsToShow().map(...` and it'll work fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-cloud-vv3ob

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks! If you want to submit that as an answer I'd be happy to accept and give you the rep. If you can, would you mind explaining why that needs to be a function in this case? I had another use case where I used filter to only show "important" notes, but that was a boolean field and worked without it being a function.

Comment: Sorry, I was way off; the only "problem" in your code was you didn't use `filterBy.toUpperCase()`; I fixed my sandbox. The logging lags because setting state is asynchronous.

Comment: No problem. I'm actually happy that I wasn't too far off then. Considering how incompetent I feel right now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself. You're doing fine, better than many people out there I would say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some changes needed in your code. I don't see why you are even getting this error `contact.name.toUpperCase` because there is nothing wrong with that.

You are converting the `contact` to upperCase but not `filterBy`.

Now, to answer your two questions:

1. You are using hooks that were introduced with react 16. This brought state to functional components. Your code will work fine with hooks or class component.
2. Whenever you make a change in any state variable (`contact, newName, newNumber, showAll, filterBy`), your component re-renders. This will call the `rows()` function and display the result that you want. So you can just push `contactsToShow` inside the function.

There is nothing breaking with your code. I don't know what `Contact` component was, so I changed it to `div` and added a console.log to see what's happening. It runs fine. Check it out:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/vibrant-dawn-o1r1y

You can let me know if you have more doubts, I'm here to help. :)

Comment: `Array.concat` returns a new array so it's fine to use; it doesn't mutate `contacts`.

Comment: So I was just a bit confused. The filtering functionality was fixed by calling toUpperCase on my filterBy state also. The function not existing error was caused by an earlier .toUpperCase where I didn't invoke with (), so JS was looking for a property there. I guess I had fixed that before I posted my code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Because you are converting 'Gordon Ramsay' to 'GORDON RAMSAY' when you do .toUpperCase() but when the filter is 'gordon', it won't filter. So you need to either do toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() on both the name and filter.

Comment: Cool. Good luck! :)